# How to Drag my view a little bit up when keyboard comes up?

Tags: iphone, uiview

In my app i have some textfields which gets filled through the keyboard. There are 6 of them and the last two are in very bottom of the screen and it gets hidden whenever keyboard comes up.
Any suggestions??

Comment: Or look at this great tutorial by Matt: http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/sliding-uitextfields-around-to-avoid.html

Comment: See step by step blog tutorial with code example .. http://iphonedevelopertips.com/user-interface/adjust-textfield-hidden-by-keyboard.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the textFields delegate as self and add the following code to the textFieldDidBeginEditing and textFieldDidEndEditing.

Define the following constants: (the constants have been set for iPad. Tweak them for iphone)

```
static const CGFloat KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION = 0.3;
static const CGFloat MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION = 0.2;
static const CGFloat MAXIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION = 0.8;
static const CGFloat PORTRAIT_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT = 216;
static const CGFloat LANDSCAPE_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT = 302;
```

Add two variables in the .h file of your class. CGFloat animatedDistance; and UITextField *currentField;

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    currentField = textField;
    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation =
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];

    CGRect textFieldRect =[self.view.window convertRect:textField.bounds fromView:textField];

    CGRect viewRect =[self.view.window convertRect:self.view.bounds fromView:self.view];
    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft )
    {
        textFieldRect.origin.y = textFieldRect.origin.x;
        textFieldRect.size.height = textFieldRect.size.width;
        viewRect.size.height = viewRect.size.width;
    }
    else  if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight )
    {
        textFieldRect.origin.y =viewRect.size.width - textFieldRect.origin.x;
        textFieldRect.size.height = textFieldRect.size.width;
        viewRect.size.height = viewRect.size.width;
    }
    else   if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    {
        textFieldRect.origin.y = viewRect.size.height - textFieldRect.origin.y;
    }

    CGFloat midline = textFieldRect.origin.y + 0.5 * textFieldRect.size.height;
    CGFloat numerator = midline - viewRect.origin.y - MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION * viewRect.size.height;
    CGFloat denominator =(MAXIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION - MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION)* viewRect.size.height;
    CGFloat heightFraction = numerator / denominator;
    if (heightFraction < 0.0)
    {
        heightFraction = 0.0;
    }
    else if (heightFraction > 1.0)
    {
        heightFraction = 1.0;
    }
    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ||
        orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    {
        animatedDistance = floor(PORTRAIT_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT * heightFraction);
    }
    else
    {
        animatedDistance = floor(LANDSCAPE_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT * heightFraction);
    }
    CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
    viewFrame.origin.y -= animatedDistance;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION];

    [self.view setFrame:viewFrame];

    [UIView commitAnimations];

}


- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    [textField resignFirstResponder];

    CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
    viewFrame.origin.y += animatedDistance;

    animatedDistance = 0;
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION];

    [self.view setFrame:viewFrame];

    [UIView commitAnimations];

    currentField = nil;
}
```

Comment: it gives me an error, which is current field undeclared and animated distance undeclared. What are these??

Comment: Oh sorry about that. You have to declare CGFloat animatedDistance; and UITextField *currentField; in the .h of your class. I'l edit the answer. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Use a UIScrollview so the user can scroll down. You can make use of the inputAccessoryView of a UITextField to show buttons like next and previous, on click let the input jump to the next textfield and scroll to it.

Have a look at this [question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5608761/how-to-make-a-uiview-scrollable) at SO, same problem, different solution.