# iOS Bring UIView up before keyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, keyboard

I have two UIViews inside my UIView. Here is my view:
[image]

On textfield focused, keyboard is shown and keyboard hides my textield. I want to move whole TextField View up before keyboard. I've found code example here on stackoverflow: 
[iPhone Keyboard Covers UITextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247113/iphone-keyboard-covers-uitextfield)

This is the code:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
  [self animateTextField: textField up: YES];
}


- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
  [self animateTextField: textField up: NO];
}

- (void) animateTextField: (UITextField*) textField up: (BOOL) up
{
  const int movementDistance = 80; // tweak as needed
  const float movementDuration = 0.3f; // tweak as needed

  int movement = (up ? -movementDistance : movementDistance);

  [UIView beginAnimations: @"anim" context: nil];
  [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState: YES];
  [UIView setAnimationDuration: movementDuration];
  self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, 0, movement);
  [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

I'm trying to implement this but I am having trouble with it. Can someone explain how to properly do that?

Comment: there are a bunch of questions regarding this problem on SOF, please google it before asking, here is the first result http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6435670/keyboard-hides-uitextfield-how-to-solve-this

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a UITextField move up when keyboard is present](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126726/how-to-make-a-uitextfield-move-up-when-keyboard-is-present)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing this manually. use [TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding).
Its easy to use.

First take UIScrollView and put ur all views inside it.

For use with UITableViewController classes, drop TPKeyboardAvoidingTableView.m and TPKeyboardAvoidingTableView.h into your project, and make your UITableView a TPKeyboardAvoidingTableView in the xib. If you're not using a xib with your controller, I know of no easy way to make its UITableView a custom class: The path of least resistance is to create a xib for it.

For non-UITableViewControllers, drop the TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView.m and TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView.h source files into your project, pop a UIScrollView into your view controller's xib, set the scroll view's class to TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView, and put all your controls within that scroll view. You can also create it programmatically, without using a xib - just use the TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView as your top-level view.

Answer (score 0):

You could write it manually using something like this:

```
- (void)makeRoomForKeyboard
{
    UIView *rootView = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate] window].rootViewController.view.subviews[0];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2f animations:^{
        rootView.center = CGPointMake(rootView.center.x, rootView.center.y - kKeyboardOffset);
    } completion:nil];
}
```

And play around with the kKeyboardOffset as you see fit.
Call this from textFieldDidBeginEditing.
When you finish editing, the same function can be called with just a + sign in front of the kKeyboardOffset.